# Can someone delete all those unused tags?

Tags: support, tags

I noticed that there are pages and pages of unused tags in the tags list. Is there any way for someone to delete them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a tag isn't in use by a question, it will naturally age out and disappear. That said, if you see some tags that don't have a number of questions beside them, it doesn't necessarily mean they're unused. I tested a bunch, and clicking on them still gets a number of questions linked to that tag, but they're tag synonyms (linked to another tag), so it doesn't seem to get the same count of questions as the main tag it is linked to does.

Comment: Even if tag synonyms are still used indirectly, it seems weird to have pages and pages of them appear like they're not used. However, I think that any meaningful solution would probably have to be developed on a network basis. At the very least, a way to hide tag synonyms could be useful.